# HEX-edit UTF-8 file

Tags: encoding, utf-8, hex, character, cp1252

I am trying to create a UTF-8/no-BOM file with a HEX-Editor. My desired UTF character is the TUGRIK SIGN, which is `e2 82 ae` in UTF-8.

I created an **UTF-8/no BOM file** with N++, copied the character in N++ and saved the file.
Voilà, looks fine in the HEX-Editor, fancy `e2 82 ae` !

So I tried it the other way arround, saving the 3 bytes `e2 82 ae` to a file with wxHexEdtior. Crap, N++ thinks for some reason that the file is **ANSI(Latin1)** encoded.

I don't get it at all. 
Might there be a collision with the windows -CP1252- encoding?

Another interesting thing (which I also don't get at all), is that wxHexEditor shows some disassembly for the files.

The disassembly for the N++ created file is okay for wxHexEditor, but the wxHexEditor created file has invalid disassembly.

I would be really glad if someone could explan that black magic to me.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Another Hex-Editor -NEXT-Soft Hex-Editor- appears to work. NP++ recognizes the document correctly as UTF-8 w/o BOM. http://12monkeys.dyndns.org/media/2012-05-01_file_by_hexeditor2.jpg

Comment: N++ has no way guessing the encoding when opening the file, so it opens with ANSI(latin1). You can just tell him what is the encoding, it will then correctly interpret the character.

Comment: NP++ apparently can do that. Just created a fresh file with Hex-Editor and NP++ chose UTF-8 wo BOM. Well, time to sleep :)

Answer (score 2):

The file itself contains no encoding information, so your editor has either to guess the encoding or just display it in some default encoding, and Latin1 is a common default. In my version of N++ (6.1.2) it opens and displays correctly as UTF-8.

If your version doesn't guess correctly, then perhaps when you created the file in N++ you told N++ in advance that you were about to create a UTF-8 file with no BOM, and that's how it knew to display it correctly at that time.

About the assembler... First, it's not a case of assembler being "linked to" or "associated with" a file, but rather that your hexeditor just tries to disassemble any file you give it.

The reason the assembler is different is that in the "good" file you happen to have selected the first byte (or nothing) and so wxHexEditor disassembles the entire file. In the "bad" version you've probably selected the second byte, and this 82 ae does not disassemble to any valid code.